# How do we understand "Being a fan is better with friends."?

Tags: meaning

> Being a fan is better with friends.

This is from a Facebook ads:

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10152894408351729

It seems to be a slogan. Literally I have a feeling that it's saying "It's better to be a fan rather than be with friends"... But I don't think that's what Facebook would say

So how should I understand it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't confuse *better with* and *better than*. They mean very different things.

These two sentences have very different meanings:

> Being a fan is **better than** [having] friends.
>   Being a fan is **better with** friends.

An example of *better with*:

> Potatoes taste **better with** salt.

That is, if you add salt to potatoes, they will taste better.

Answer (score 3):

It's saying "your experience of being a fan will be enhanced or improved if you have friends with you (while you are being a fan)".

*X is Y with Z* means that adding Z to X will make X become Y.

Answer (score 1):

> Being a fan is better with friends.

As an example, lets say you are going to a pro baseball game or another sporting event where your favorite team is playing. You are a fan of the team, and hope they win. You also want to have a fun time watching the game. Sure, you could still likely enjoy the game if you went alone, but if you brought friends with you, you'd likely have a better time, than just being by yourself.